# Select attribute not getting set

Tags: jquery, html-select

None of these set the value to contain the word selected. This means that when the select list gets passed back to php the selection become 'undone':

```
 jQuery("#tag_photo2").val("<?php echo $pg->m2; ?>").attr("selected",true);
    jQuery("#tag_photo2").val("<?php echo $pg->m2; ?>").attr('selected','selected');
    jQuery("#tag_photo2").val("<?php echo $pg->m2; ?>").prop("selected",true);
```

The following shows that the selection is actually known:

```
jQuery("#value2").html($("#tag_photo2 :selected").text() + " (VALUE: " + $("#tag_photo2").val() + ")");
```

as I get 'CURRENT SELECTED: test123 (VALUE: 2)' displayed.

The selection here is correct, but if sent to php it get lost.

Tried with jQuery 1.8.2 and 1.7.1, Firefox 15.0.1 and Chrome 22.0.1229.94.

Have searched around and can't find any other ways to set the 'selected' word in the value field of an option.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Random side note, mixing back-end within front-end coding is a bad coding practice, you should have a separation of concerns. Grab the element in another way.

Comment: If you have the values server side (in php) you could simply set them in the html/php instead of doing it client side with javascript.

Comment: You have to set the `selected` attribute on the `option` elements not the `select`.

Comment: @Musa OK, makes sense that it needs to be set on the option. So tried: jQuery('#tag_photo1 option[value="<?php echo $pg->model1; ?>"]').attr('selected','selected'); which after php looks like: jQuery('#tag_photo1 option[value="2"]').attr('selected','selected'); Which I found from [link] (stackoverflow.com/questions/1311287/…) Still doesn't work.

Comment: How are you sending this data? I mean lets say you used a static entry, is this being sent to a controller?

Comment: @worthycaesar This is embedded in html after being processed by php. For problem detail check out [link] (http://mackievisions.com/ProblemExample.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try .prop instead of .attr

```
$("#selectIDGoesHere > option[value='valueOfTheOptionHere']").prop("selected", true);
jQuery('#tag_photo1 > option[value="2"]').prop('selected',true)
```

Also, if you're using any plugins that skins the select like Chosen or Select2, you have to refresh them.